# Replacing stdin within a piece of code

Tags: c, stdin

I have a piece of code that uses stdin. When I run the program from command-line I pass it the location of a wav file i.e. /Users/username/Desktop/music.wav.

The code is written only in C. The stdin variable runs throughout 2 functions.

How would I replace the stdin within the code with the input of the file directory and location?

In other words, how do I hard code '/Users/username/Desktop/music.wav' into two different C functions.

Comment: From previous similar questions he seems to be using Mac OS X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [freopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/freopen/).

If I understand correctly, you read the filename from `argv[1]` and call freopen():

```
freopen(argv[1], "r", stdin);
```

Comment: @Simone. Really? Isn't it just a matter of passing a string somehow?

Comment: @Simone. Plus, this seems to be for stdout. Would it work for stdin?

Comment: @Simone. hmmm... Maybe I'm being a bit ignorant here, but doesn't this still mean I need to pass the filename as an argument via the command line? I would like the file to be hardcoded within the code. Apologies if I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I wish to encourage hardwiring of course ....

It sounds like you wish to define the file location & reference it from multiple locations ?

You could #define the path in a header & then include that in multiple files.

E.g.

header.h

```
#define FILE_LOCATION "/Users/username/Desktop/music.wav"
```

myProgram.c

```
#include "header.h"

void functionA() {
    fopen(FILE_LOCATION, ...);

    /* 
     * etc ..
     */
}

void functionB() {

    printf("The file is %s\n", FILE_LOCATION);

    /* 
     * etc ..
     */
}
```

myOtherProgram.c

```
#include "header.h"

void someOtherFunction() {
   doSomethingWith(FILE_LOCATION);
}

void doSomethingWith(char *fileLoc) {

}
```